# How can I define a FileSystemAccessRule in PowerShell that has the property IsInherited set to true?

Tags: powershell, access-rights

For testing purposes I want to define a [FileSystemAccessRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule?view=net-8.0) with the property `IsInherited` set to `true` in PowerShell, for example:

```
FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

However, the [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule?view=net-8.0#constructors) for `FileSystemAccessRule` do not seem to contain any parameters that modify this property, only the other 5 properties. Furthermore, the property is `ReadOnly`. So when I try to modify it after it has been created:

```
$fileSystemAccessRule.IsInherited = $true
```

The following error is thrown: `'IsInherited' is a ReadOnly property.`

**How can I create a `FileSystemAccessRule` with `IsInherited` set to `true`, so I can test it against existing access rules for given files?**

Comment: Have you looked at [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-security-accesscontrol-filesystemaccessrule-ctor(system-security-principal-identityreference-system-security-accesscontrol-filesystemrights-system-security-accesscontrol-inheritanceflags-system-security-accesscontrol-propagationflags-system-security-accesscontrol-accesscontroltype)) and followed the link to [InheritanceFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags) ?

Comment: Create a folder, add a new propagated ACE, then create a new file and grab the inherited ACE from the new file :)

Comment: @Theo, yes I have used these constructors, I also linked them in my question. Inheritance flags only play a role once a FileSystemAccessRule has been applied I think, then the `IsInherited` property would become `true` for children of the applied container (depending on what has been set as an inheritance flag). But I want it to be true for the object that I defined in memory.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, that is a dirty workaround that works :) Not sure if I want to use it in my tests, was hoping for a more straightforward solution that works just in memory. If you write it up I would accept it as an answer, since it is a solution for my problem. Sadly the `IsInherited` flag is set to `false` again, once the fetched access rule gets applied to a file/directory security object in memory again.

Comment: @dan-kli I might be able to suggest something less "dirty" if you tell us a little more about the actual problem you're trying to solve - what exact test can't your perform without `IsInherited` set to `$true`?

Comment: It is quite simple. I want to test if permissions are applied correctly. I have arrays of objects of type `FileSystemSecurity` that I fetch with `Get-ACL`. Some of the access rules within them are inherited, some are not. I want to test them against expected predefined access rules. However I can only define expected access rules that are not inherited... so I cannot define all access rules against which I want to test.

Comment: Ideally I could store multiple `FileSystemAccessRules` in predefined objects of type `DirectorySecurity` or `FileSystemSecurity`. Then I could e.g. define something like `$expectedDirectoryPermissions_A` for a certain directory type, which contains both inherited and set permissions, and test against these objects, which would lead to very readable and simple tests. But that does not work, since I cannot add inherited permissions to `DirectorySecurity` or `FileSystemSecurity` in memory...

Comment: @dan-kli Instances of `FileSystemAccessRule` are not directly comparable, so you might as well store your reference data in a hashtable or custom object - since you'll need to implement the comparison routine yourself anyway :)

Comment: Yup, I already implemented the comparison routine, I combine all properties of `FileSystemAccessRule` to a hash and use `Compare-Object`.  This includes the `IsInherited` property. Yeah a custom object was also my idea, thing is I am using externally predefined permissions, and I want to use them as they are for my tests. But I guess I have to use one of the possible workarounds, mapping the predefined permissions to custom objects are one option. Basically there are different workarounds, and all are ugly... but thanks for your help

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I would still accept your original comment as an answer, since that is a (dirty) solution to what my original question was.